# Files images, docx corrupted/cant open when download from server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pdf files are OK but files images, docx cant open/corrupted when I download from server

```
$file = APPPATH . '/upload/filename.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');


    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Remove slash from concatenate string i.e. `'upload/filename.jpg'` - `APPPATH` is already ending with slash.

Comment: @Tpojka  I did but it cant open image, doc file, file pdf is good

Comment: For `.docx` files try with `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');`.

Answer (score 0):

The official way with Codeigniter is to use the Download helper: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html. In your instance you may be better off trying http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php `is_readable()` as this checks for existance as well as if PHP can read (to then use) it.